# Incorrect print rendering of italic fonts in chrome

Tags: css, fonts, google-chrome, printing

I have an HTML page with a rendering issue where italic fonts are being clipped by what appears to be the bounding box of the next letter.  I've tested this on a HP LJ5100 with postscript (the only printer I have to hand at the moment).  This only manifests itself when the page is rendered from Chrome - it renders fine on Firefox.

Here's an example of the rendered text, captured by printing to a file and rendering with gsview.

[image: Example of clipped glyphs]

My google-fu fails me.  Is this a known bug with chrome or something to do with fonts being set up wrong on the page?

Code to reproduce (HTML)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page title</title>       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/RenderingTest.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-content">
    <table class="specs">
      <tr>
      <td class="foo">
        <ul class="foo">
          <li class="foo">Blurb. <br><em><strong>Weight:</strong> 0.2t, <strong>price:</strong> Cr24,600.</em></li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

(And a stylesheet)

```
div#main-content { 
    margin-top: 7em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    border-left: 1px solid #404040;
}

li {
    font: 90%/1.25 Tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    text-indent: -1em;
    list-style-type: square;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

table.specs {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    font: 80%/1.25 Tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #404040;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 2em;
    max-width: 40em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-left: 13em;
    /*border-left: 1px solid #404040;*/
    /*margin-bottom: 2em;*/
}

td.foo {
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

ul.foo {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

li.foo {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 2.5em;
    padding: 0em;
    list-style-type: square;
    list-style-position: outside;
    text-indent: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```